# 'max-width' property doesn't work when child elements are floated?

Tags: html, css

I would like to set `max-width` on a container element whose child elements are floated. How do I do it?

By default, the `max-width` property doesn't work in the given scenario (but `min-width` does). [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/its_me/bJG54/) that you can use to help me with the question.

Look in the fiddle's preview pane -- this is what I am talking about (`.dropdown-menu` class defines the relevant style):

[image: min-width not working]

But this is what it's supposed to look like (somewhat):

[image: preview of how it's supposed to look like]

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I've never used *codepen* before....... Where's the **run** button? :S

Comment: @its_me - remove `position:absolute` from `.dropdown-menu` class and it will work !! i have updated the pan code

Comment: @F4r-20 It is split screen... top is code, bottom is display

Comment: [check this](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/hzDaG)

Comment: @Ladineko Am I missing something? Does it automatically update? Because all I see is a big white space.

Comment: @F4r-20 There's no run button afaik (I am a new user too). Just fork and save.

Comment: @F4r-20 above the white space you see the menu bar. and thats the result :)

Comment: OH HAHA! I thought that was a CodePen menu. It's early in the morning.

Comment: @F4r-20 - just edit the code and click on `FORK` and then `SAVE` and copy that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These quotes should answer the question:

> A floated box is positioned within the normal flow, then taken out of the flow and shifted to the left or right as far as possible. Content may flow along the side of a float.
>
> When a box is taken out of normal flow, all content that is still within normal flow will ignore it completely and not make space for it.
>
> You should always set a width on floated items (except if applied directly to an image – which has implicit width). If no width is set, the results can be unpredictable.
>
> For one, the box being floated should have a width defined for it, either explicitly or implicitly. Otherwise, it will fill its containing block horizontally, just like non-floated content, leaving no room for other content to flow around it. Second, unlike boxes in the normal flow, the vertical margins of a floated box are not collapsed with the margins of boxes either above or below it. Finally, a floated box can overlap block-level boxes adjacent to it in the normal flow.

**- via [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/)**

So, your only options are `min-width` and `width`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `position:absolute;` with `position:fixed;`

and change `left:0px;` to `left:35px;`

**UPDATED PEN** : http://codepen.io/joe/pen/hzDaG

Comment: can't remove `position:absolute` as the menu will no longer be positioned properly. :(

Comment: @its_me - I am not getting position problem after removing it. :-/ Can u please show me what is going wrong after removing it? :-/

Comment: ohh i see the problem !! wait !

Comment: That solution would work only for that menu item because the previous menu item is just an icon and has a specific width. This is not the case with the other menu items that also have text in their name (meaning their width varies from OS to OS, or even browser to browserm depending on font-rendering). Do you get the idea of what I am trying to say? Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position:absolute` to `position: fixed;` in `.dropdown-menu`

`width/height:100%` wont work with absolute position.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 36px;
    left: 35px; 
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
   max-width: 100% !important; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color: #222;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Arav8/9/)**

Comment: The reason why I did not use `position: fixed;` is that it's not a good choice in cases like mine, where you don't know the exact position the dropdown needs to be placed from left or right (e.g. `left: xxxx;` or `right: xxxx;`

Comment: That solution would work only for that menu item because the previous menu item is just an icon and has a specific width. This is not the case with the other menu items that also have text in their name (meaning their width varies from OS to OS, or even browser to browserm depending on font-rendering). Do you get the idea of what I am trying to say? Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use with instead of max width, works that way.. Or put a div to enclose the ul tags then put a width

Comment: .. put a width to the div enclosing the UL tags

Comment: Really..? Worked for me when I tried in chrome, just edited the html using inspect element, added this: <div style="width: 600px;"> .. </div> to enclose the UL tags. Not sure if this is good though, eliminates the purpose of having a dynamic width that stretches so will get back to you..

Comment: Ah... you were talking about `width`, but I was talking about `min-width`. I am creating  a responsive layout, and can't specify widths.

Comment: Yeah sorry just noticed, with should be width in my post, sorry for the typo hehe. I see thought you'd say that. Will get back to you then.